# <div> in HTML seems to be empty (web scraping in r with rvest)

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape some data from a betting website using the r library rvest. 
In order to get the values, I need to click some hyperlinks in a table. 
To do so I use the following code:

```
odds_link <- "https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/germany/bundesliga/results/"
odds_page <- read_html(odds_link)
node_table <- html_node(xpath = '//*[@id="tournamentTable"]')
```

I used this [xpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fF5Hy.png) and node_table returns this

```
{xml_nodeset (1)}
[1] <div id="tournamentTable"></div>\n
```

The returned node looks empty since there is nothing between the div tags... It should look like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HImMD.png). 
At this point, I am very lost. I have tried a couple of things but was not successful.

```
node_table %>% html_node("table")
node_table %>% html_table()
node_table %>% html_structure()
```

This was returned:

```
> node_table %>% html_node("table")
{xml_missing}
<NA>
> node_table %>% html_table()
Fehler in html_table.xml_node(.) : html_name(x) == "table" is not TRUE
> node_table %>% html_structure()
<div#tournamentTable>
```

I would greatly appreciate help on this!
(The next step would be to access [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2zku.png) hyperlinks in the table.) 
 I even can not access the hyperlink...

```
xpath_link = '//*[@id="tournamentTable"]/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/a'
odds_page %>% html_node(xpath = xpath_link)
```

```
> odds_page %>% html_node(xpath = xpath_link)
{xml_missing}
<NA>
```

Comment: That table is rendered by Javascript. You probably need [`RSelenium`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/index.html) for this task.

Answer (score 0):

A `RSelenium` solution,

Launch browser

```
library(RSelenium)
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
driver = rsDriver(port = 4492L, browser = c("firefox"))
remDr <- driver[["client"]]
remDr$navigate(url)
```

**Get Table**

```
remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
    read_html() %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="tournamentTable"]') %>% 
    html_table()


# A tibble: 82 x 7
   `Soccer» Germany»Bundesliga` `Soccer» Germany»Bundesliga`  `Soccer» Germany»Bundesliga` `Soccer» Germany~ `Soccer» German~ `Soccer» German~ `Soccer» German~
   <chr>                        <chr>                         <chr>                                    <dbl> <chr>                       <dbl> <chr>           
 1 "19 Dec 2021"                "19 Dec 2021"                 "19 Dec 2021"                             1    "X"                          2    "B's"           
 2 ""                           ""                            ""                                       NA    ""                          NA    ""              
 3 "16:30"                      "FC Koln - Stuttgart"         "1:0"                                     1.97 "3.90"                       3.63 "15"
```

**Get the links**

```
 remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes('.table-participant') %>% html_nodes('a') %>% 
   html_attr('href')

 [1] "/soccer/germany/bundesliga/1-fc-koln-vfb-stuttgart-Y3cdUviO/"               "/soccer/germany/bundesliga/freiburg-bayer-leverkusen-rF4qXt75/"            
 [3] "/soccer/germany/bundesliga/hertha-berlin-dortmund-4UhhVKyI/"                "/soccer/germany/bundesliga/bochum-union-berlin-Cfd0Tb6U/"
```